# Wordcloud with each line as input R

Tags: r, word-cloud

I have a file with one column and 190178 lines,  a few lines of which looks like this:

```
anatomical_structure_development
nucleic_acid_binding_transcription_factor_activity
molecular_function
biological_process
biosynthetic_process
cellular_nitrogen_compound_metabolic_process
embryo_development
anatomical_structure_formation_involved_in_morphogenesis
immune_system_process
biosynthetic_process
cellular_nitrogen_compound_metabolic_process
embryo_development
```

I want to make a wordcloud of this data using the **tm** and **wordcloud** package in R, taking each line as input, and making the wordcloud with the frequency of each line's occurrence. I've tried this using simple instructions from "speech" corpus formats but in that way, the word "process" has the highest frequency and gets the largest size, which is not what I want. I want the line with the highest frequency to be the largest.

I used the following code from common examples, but didn't get what I desired:

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
GO <- Corpus(DirSource("/home/student-a/Desktop/Untitled Folder/"))
wordcloud(GO)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question.

Comment: Do you need "embryo_development" in the word cloud or embryo and development as separate words?

Comment: @phiver "embryo_development" as one word. There is no whitespace in my file. Each line has words joined by "_".

Comment: What you will run into if you keep the words as text is that the words are too long for wordcloud. you will see the following warning `anatomical_structure_formation_involved_in_morphogenesis could not be fit on page. It will not be plotted.` You might want to look at some other packages like wordcloud2 or an online [wordcloud generator](https://www.wordclouds.com/).

Comment: I tried wordcloud generator online but I have too many lines, and it takes forever. Do you have any solution to this? Possibly with wordcloud2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on the example, but with wordcloud2. wordcloud gives warnings when the words are too long. Though wordcloud2 is also not very fast in drawing and you need to open the viewer to see the result

> anatomical_structure_formation_involved_in_morphogenesis could not be
>   fit on page. It will not be plotted.

**Code with wordcloud2:**

```
library(wordcloud2)
library(dplyr)

text <- c("anatomical_structure_development",
          "nucleic_acid_binding_transcription_factor_activity",
          "molecular_function",
          "biological_process",
          "biosynthetic_process",
          "cellular_nitrogen_compound_metabolic_process",
          "embryo_development",
          "anatomical_structure_formation_involved_in_morphogenesis",
          "immune_system_process",
          "biosynthetic_process",
          "cellular_nitrogen_compound_metabolic_process",
          "embryo_development")

# wordcloud2 needs a data.frame with frequencies. This will generate the table from the text.
df <- text %>% data_frame(words = .) %>% 
  group_by(words) %>% 
  summarise(freq = n())

wordcloud2(df)
```